# Load another domain images to my domain using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 domains and 2 servers **`example.com`** and **`example2.com`**. for eg: **`example.com`** is my main domain. i upload my site images into **`example2.com`**

my current image path `http://example.com/data/photos/sample.jpg`.
but my all images are in `http://example2.com/data/photos/sample.jpg`

So i create htaccess **301** redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^data/photos/(.*)$ http://example2.com/data/photos/$1 [R=301]
```

But its not working for me. Because of i called full URL into my all pages. so any one suggestion its very helpful for me

**Updated** my old Htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^data/photos/(.*)$ http://example2/data/photos/$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you have a simple typo. You need *photos* there.

Comment: @ Ravi Thapliyal ya i have photos in example2.com domain

Comment: So, just correct your rules. You have used  *photo* there.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal its my spell mistake. now i update it. its also not working

Comment: Where is your htaccess located? Are there any other rules?

Comment: my htaccess in my public_html folder. i will show my full htaccess in my question

Comment: **its not working** is not enough. What exact problem are you getting? Is it 404 or something else with photos? Why not update your image links to `http://example2/data/photos/...`

Comment: @anubhava Yeah, good 'ol find and replace. Not to mention the page load times would also be heavily improved.

Comment: guys its not reflected into my page. That is my problem. nothing else

Comment: @NathanSrivi You won't the see the url change in your page's source. It's just the browser will fetch the images from the redirected URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to reorder your rules. Your final htaccess should look something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^(data/photos/.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: its also not working for me. whats wrong. if i remove entire htaccess code means site not working. please help me

Comment: Can you provide the site address so I can debug the requests?

Comment: On your homepage none of the links load an image from data/photos. They all came from themes folder. I need a link where you're facing the issue to be able to help you.

Comment: Yeah, the redirect is working fine on my browser. The URL changed to img.picture.lk in my address bar. Maybe you just need to delete your cache or try with another browser.

Comment: Its working from Background. thanks @Ravi Thapliyal. thank you so muchh

Answer (score 6):

change it with this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/data/photo/ http://example2.com/data/photo/
```

to create a 301 for the entire directory.

Comment: Since the match is static you can also use `Redirect 301 /data/photo http://example2.com/data/photo`

Comment: I need to redirect to external domain path if image are loading from photo directory

Comment: I love the elegance of this solution. Just remember that RedirectMatch requires `mod_alias`, not the more well-known `mod_rewrite`.