# Show another domain images to my domain using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this code in .htaccess but its not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(img/uploads/.*)$ https://www.otherdomain.com/images/upload/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

i want to show image in my site but without showing otherdomain url.  is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible with `mod-proxy` .You just need to enable the proxy module on your Apache server. See the documentation here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668125/load-another-domain-images-to-my-domain-using-htaccess